# Aggregate (join) text column based on conditions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I have a dataset as follow:

```
task = ['duty of care','informed consent','records management','conducting','experiments','positive reinforcement','developing','rapport' ]
start = [ 21, 24, 26,  60, 61, 80,98,99 ]
end = [ 24, 26, 28,  61,  62, 82,99,100]

dat = pd.DataFrame({'task': task, 'start':start, 'end': end})
dat
```

[image]

What I want to accomplish is this

1. if `dat.end[i] == dat.start[i+1]` then aggregate `dat.task`
2. if `dat.end[i] != dat.start[i+1]` do nothing

The desired output should look like this.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

We'll want a way to group these together if they're part of a block. First, let's find all the times where the start does not equal the next item's end. This series is True if an item is the first in a block and false otherwise.

```
temp = (dat['start'] != dat['end'].shift(1))
```

It looks like this:

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
6     True
7    False
```

We can then take a cumulative sum. When you do that to True/False, True will add 1 to the sum and False's won't change it. This is useful because it then gives us a *grouping* -- every block that you wanted to combine originally has it's own number associated with it.

```
groups = temp.cumsum()
```

looks like:

```
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    3
6    4
7    4
```

Now we're almost there. For every group, you want to grab the min start, the max end, and concatenate all the text.

```
datg = dat.groupby(groups)
out = pd.DataFrame({
    'task':  datg['task'].apply(' '.join),
    'start': datg['start'].min(),
    'end':   datg['end'].max(),
})
```

That gives a final result of:

```
                                               task  start  end
1  duty of care informed consent records management     21   28
2                            conducting experiments     60   62
3                            positive reinforcement     80   82
4                                developing rapport     98  100
```

Putting it all in one place:

```
temp = (dat['start'] != dat['end'].shift(1))
groups = temp.cumsum()
datg = dat.groupby(groups)
out = pd.DataFrame({
    'task':  datg['task'].apply(' '.join),
    'start': datg['start'].min(),
    'end':   datg['end'].max(),
    })
```

Comment: You can replace the ```apply(" ".join)``` with ```agg(" ".join)```. I'd like to think it be faster. never really tested it though

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can first create a new column using `cumsum` and `groupby` that column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'task': task, 'start':start, 'end': end})

df["count"] = (df["start"]-df["end"].shift(1)).fillna(0).ne(0).cumsum()
print (df.groupby("count").agg({"task":"first","start":"min","end":"max"}))

                         task  start  end
count                                    
0                duty of care     21   28
1                  conducting     60   62
2      positive reinforcement     80   82
3                  developing     98  100
```